# Integrating CKEditor in Dynamics NAV

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to integrate the CKEditor in Dynamics NAV. Dynamics NAV allows to integrate JavaScript AddIns. Unfortunately, there are some restrictions. One of these restrictions is the strict folder hierarchy for all the files, that belong to the addin. In order to import such a JavaScript Addin, the developer has to create a .ZIP file with a manifest.xml file in the root and three subfolders for Script, Stylesheet and Image. As you can imagine, if I split all files from CKEditor and its plugins and put them into the new folder structure, the editor won't work. On the other hand, if I leave them in their original folder structure, the AddIn could not be imported into Dynamics NAV.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put any Third-party software components on the IIS / NAV Webserver.

reference the js inside the Manifest.xml with:

```
<ScriptUrls>
<ScriptUrl>https://yourserver/ckeditor_version/ckeditor.js</ScriptUrl>
</ScriptUrls>
```

This is the offical way for all components:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/manifest-overview